# achieve better recognition results via training tesseract

Tags: ocr, tesseract, training-data

I have a question regarding achieving better recognition results with tesseract. I am using tesseract to recognize serial numbers. The serial numbes consist of only one font-type, characters A-Z, 0-9 and occur in different sizes and lengths.

At the moment I am able to recognize about 40% of the serial number images correct. Images are taken via mobile phone camera. Therefore the image quality isn't the best.

Special problem characters are 8/B, 5/6. Since I am recognizing only serial numbers, I am not using any dictionary improvements and every character is recognized independently.

My question is: Does someone has already experience in achieving better recognition results with training tesseract? How many images would be needed to be able to get good results.

For training tesseract should I use printed and afterwards photographed serial numbers, or should I use original digital serial numbers, without printing and photographing?

Maybe somebody has already experience in that kind of area.

Regarding training tesseract: I have already trained tesseract with some images. Therefore I have printed all characters in different sizes, photographed and labeled them correctly. Example training photo of the character 5

[image]

Is this a good/bad training example? Since I only want to recognize single characters without any dependency, I though I don't have to use words for training.

Actual I only have trained with 3 of these images for the characters *B 8 6 5* which doesn't result in a better recognition in comparison with the original english (eng) tesseract database.

best regards, 
Christoph

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on a Sikuli application using Tesseract to read text (Strings and numbers) from screenshots. I found that the best way to achieve accuracy was to process the screenshot before performing the OCR on it. However, most of the text I am reading is green text-on black background, making this my preferred solution. I used [Scalr's](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/) method within BufferedImage to increase the size of the image:

```
BufferedImage bufImg = Scalr.resize(...)
```

which instantly yielded more accurate results with black text on gray background. I then used BufferedImage's options `BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY` and `BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY` when creating a new BufferedImage to process the Image to grayscale and black/white, respectively.

Following these steps brought Tesseract's accuracy from a 30% to around an 85% when dealing with green text on black background, and a really-close-to-100%  accuracy when dealing with normal black text on white background. (sometimes letters within a word are mistaken by numbers i.e. hel10)
I hope this helps!

Comment: Your link goes to some spam website

Comment: As described in the question [How to get the most accurate results with Tesseract OCR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48416810/how-to-get-the-most-accurate-results-with-tesseract-ocr), you can use ImageMagik to scale the image before the OCR processing.