# How to get the most accurate results with Tesseract OCR

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

I'm in the process of building/training Tesseract to recognize passport MRZ codes from a captured photo. I'm applying the following image pre-processing techniques before the photo/image is being sent to the Tesseract engine:

- Binarization
- Normalization
- Sampling
- Denoising
- Thinning (optionally)

Furthermore I've already trained the Tesseract engine with the correct font (OCR-B) by creating numerous box files (from 35 or so samples that contain photos taken from textual samples of OCR-B font), fixing any mistakes in the box files, creating training files and finally training the Tesseract engine with all my samples and generating a traineddata file.

However even after all this Tesseract 3.04 in C# (engine mode = Default, pagesegmode = Auto) with my custom traineddata still makes simply mistakes such as:

- Confusing alphabet characters with numeric ones (or vice versa) for example S and 5, B and 8.

Now for my question, what can I do so that Tesseract produces much more accurate results? My 30 training samples consisted of photos taken from:

1. Passports
2. Typed word pages with OCR-B font

Sample of what the input image would look like compared to what Tessearct receives:
[image: Image before and after pre-processing]

Comment: I observed the same problem with reading MRZ zone with tesseract - 0 to O, 8 to B and vice versa. My first approach was user patterns but apparently they do not work with tesseract at all. Then I did all possible variations of the ocred string with both 8 and B, 0 and O and so on. This gives you _a lot_ of variants but usually the right string is there. You can limit this operations only for digits (in the date of birth section) and skip names for example ( because there is no checksum for them  I think).

Answer (score 1):

Scale up to 480% using imagemagick convert program. Also introduce sharpening and whitening. Gives dramatic improvements. I see better results than many bought OCR programs doing this.